# How do I check if set of values are (including nans) are present in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I have a list of special values like `[-999, np.nan]` that I want to check if they're available in a pd.Series such as `pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, -999])`.

This code below works as intended:

```
-999 in pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, -999]).values
>>> True
```

However, the code below returns False, when I would have expected it to be True:

```
np.nan in pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, -999]).values
>>> False
```

How can I evaluate if `np.nan` is in the series without using something as `isnull()` or any null specific functions?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
In [3]: pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, -999]).isna().any()                            
Out[3]: True
```

If you want to check for specific values, you can use `isin`. Here's an example:

```py
In [4]: pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, -999]).isin([np.nan, -999]).any()             
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: I want to avoid all null specific functions, as I also want to check if values such as -999 are present.